# How to ignore accessibility hidden text in Capybara

Tags: capybara

```
<a href="/link/12345" class="dont-print report-link">
                        Explore 
<span class="govuk-visually-hidden">report data</span>
in detail
</a>
```

I can't seem to click link using `click_link("Explore in detail")` as there's is hidden text for accessibility that is being picked up.
How do I click using text? Not particularly keen on clicking using href.

Answer (score 0):

`locators` (the primary non-keyword parameter) passed to Capybara selectors are matched against multiple attributes of the elements being located. In the case of the `link` selector that is the id, title, text content, descendant imgs alt, aria-label (if configured), and a test id (if configured). Visibility of the things being matched against is not considered for performance reasons, only the returned elements visibility is checked (in default configuration). If you need to locate a link by visible contained text you can instead pass the `text` option which does take visibility into account.

```
click_link(text: "Explore in detail")
```

This is a lot less efficient than a locator based search, so it might be worth scoping to a specific section of the page if you have a lot of links. Another possible option is to click based on the class(es)

```
click_link(class: 'report-link')
```

or

```
click_link(class: ['dont-print', 'report-link'])
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Doesn't work with the text option either. May be because of how it's hidden? Already knew about the class option which works.

Comment: @Rahul - How exactly does it look on the page - ie is CSS modfiying the case, etc. Easy way to check is by finding the element using a different method and looking at `element.text` to see what it shows

Comment: `element.text` returns the invisible text too "Explore report data in detail" instead of "Explore in detail". The `.govuk-visually-hidden` style is as follows 
```.govuk-visually-hidden, .govuk-visually-hidden-focusable {
    position: absolute!important;
    width: 1px!important;
    height: 1px!important;
    margin: 0!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0)!important;
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%)!important;
    clip-path: inset(50%)!important;
    white-space: nowrap!important;```

Comment: @Rahul - what driver are you using?

Comment: Using selenium-webdriver. Capybara version 3.29.0

Comment: @Rahul - oh - you're hiding it by making it a 1px square - yeah - that's not really hidden from the page since it does have presence in the page flow - just do `click_link('Explore report data in detail')` or `click_link(text: 'Explore report data in detail')` - not much more you can do if it's not actually removed from the page flow.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Thomas. I will see if the elements can be hidden another way.